# Compare datetime fields without time element

Tags: mysql

Currently I have the following line:

```
AND date_sent + INTERVAL 3 DAY <= NOW()
```

However this doesn't get results where the time is later than NOW(), how would I simply compare dates in date_sent that were 3 days later than the original?

Comment: `date_sent <= DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL 3 DAY ) )`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That seems to return every row

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking I solved it using:

```
AND DATE(value_sent) + INTERVAL 3 DAY <= CURDATE()
```